# Автоматически нажать на кнопку "наверх" на сайте ВК

Tags: javascript, вконтакте

Пытаюсь автоматически нажать на кнопку "наверх" на сайте ВК, но она по непонятным мне причинам не нажимается) В javascript разбираюсь плохо, вот мой код, который я пробывал:

```
    $("#stl_bg").click();
и
    document.getElementById('stl_bg').click();
```

Comment: Посмотрите, как сделал бы я:

    $("#stl_bg").click(function() {
         $("html, body").animate({scrollTop: 0}, "slow");
    });

разница в том, что у вас не указана сама функция, которая "поднимает сайт верх".

Comment: Но ведь эта функция уже есть на сайте ВК. Осталось ее вызвать.

Comment: @hjacob30 извините, не так прочитал. Возможно, вы имеете ввиду: 
    
    $("#stl_bg").trigger('click');

Но я не уверен, что у вас получится.

Comment: Все равно не работает.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$('#stl_left').dispatchEvent(new Event('mousedown'))
```

так у меня сработало.

Интересно почему событие не на click, а на mousedown?

Comment: Видимо обработчик поставлен именно на событие "mousedown"?

Comment: Да. Вот это мне и интересно) Почему вместо стандартного click разработчики vk сделали mousedown

Comment: @MrFranke, думаю при разработке таких проектов нужно писать немного нестандартные решения, чтобы многочисленным кулхацкерам не легко писАлись букмарклеты. Ну, это так, мое предположение

Comment: Все намного проще: для лучшей совместимости с сенсорными дисплеями.